# How do you triangulate a number in python?

Tags: python

I have to do these for school and I don't know how to.

Write a function `print_triangular_numbers(n)` that prints out the first n triangular numbers (n is an input). A call to `print_triangular_numbers(5)` would produce the following output:

```
n result
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 10
5 15
```

Comment: What is the relation between the first and second right hand side numbers? What is the relation between the 2nd and 3rd, asf?

Btw. this is really not a "write my assignment code for me" service. Please read up on how to ask questions.

Comment: What is the pattern in those numbers? Figure it out and turn it into code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework

Answer (score 0):

A [triangular number](https://oeis.org/A000217) can be expressed as

```
n(n+1)/2
```

Thus, you need to build a simple loop, starting at 1 and going through your passed parameter:

```
def print_triangular_numbers(n):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        print x, x * (x + 1) / 2
```

The `for` loop starts at 1 and goes through `n+1` because `range` is not inclusive of the end point.

This outputs:

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 10
5 15
```